# Glyphicons don't work

Tags: css, asp.net

I use bootstrap-cosmo.css v3.3.7 and file contain glyphicon -glyphicon-duplicate

```
.glyphicon-duplicate:before {
content: "\e224";
}
```

but when I use it. It won't show up.

```
<a class="btn btn-danger btn-circle">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-duplicate"></i>
</a>
```

Any suggestion? I am using .NET ASP

Glyphicon like glyphicon glyphicon-remove works fine.

Comment: you have to add glyphicon font file on your web page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your stylesheets links and bootstrap load. 
[Here](https://codepen.io/aska-g/pen/zPNPjE) you can see it work fine.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This will help, but it replaced my bootstrap-cosmo so the page look different.